# No imprime el arreglo en la tabla

Tags: array, angularjs, ng-repeat

estoy comenzando en angularJS, lleve acabo una práctica para hacer un carrito de compras, se elige un producto de la lista, se ingresa una cantidad de productos y debe mostrar en una tabla detalle como: nombre, precio, total, total de la cuenta, etc. 
En la parte de código, "addAlCarrito" se declara una función que debe llenar el arreglo que esta vacío, después en el index se debe mostrar con un ng-repeat, rellenando los espacios de la tabla y haciendo los calculos que indicia el archivo.js no muestra nada en la tabla ¿a que podría deberse?
Adjunto código

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controlador", function($scope){
    var lista = this;
    var n= 6;
    var nCarrito = 1;
    lista.productos = [
        {id: 1, nombre: "Florero vidrio", precio: 100.0},
        {id: 2, nombre: "Florero plastico", precio: 70.0},
        {id: 3, nombre: "Florero metal", precio: 80.0},
        {id: 4, nombre: "Papel kraft", precio: 50.0},
        {id: 5, nombre: "Papel celofan", precio: 40.0},
        {id: 6, nombre: "liston", precio: 30.0}
    ];
    
    lista.carrito = [];

    lista.addProducto = function(){
        var nombre = lista.nombre;
        var precio = lista.precio;

        if(nombre != "" && precio != "" && !isNaN(precio)){
            n++;
            lista.productos.push({id: n, nombre: nombre, precio: precio});

            lista.nombre = '';
            lista.precio = '';
        }
    }

    lista.addAlCarrito = function(){
        var id = lista.productoSeleccionado;
        var cantidad = lista.cantidad;
        var producto = lista.productos.find(function(obj){
            return obj.id == id;
        });
        if(producto != undefined && cantidad > 0) {
            lista.carrito.push({id: nCarrito, nombre: producto.nombre, precio: producto.precio, cantidad: cantidad, total: producto.precio * cantidad});
            nCarrito++;
        }
    }

    lista.getTotalCarrito = function(){
        var total = 0;
        lista.carrito.forEach(x => {
            total += x.total
        });

        return total;
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#menu{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
#menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li a{
    color: royalblue;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container{
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

input[type="text"]{
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none; 
}
input[type="button"]{
    background-color: darkblue;
    border: 0;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    outline: none;
}

table{
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
thead{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}

td{
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee
}

.total{
    background-color: #222 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controlador as lista">
    <h2>Añade productos a tu cuenta</h2>
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="lista.productoSeleccionado">
        <option ng-repeat="producto in lista.productos" value="{{prodcuto.id}}">{{producto.nombre}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lista.cantidad">
    <input type="button" value="Añadir" ng-click="lista.addAlCarrito">

    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Producto</td>
                <td>Precio</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="producto in lista.carrito">
            <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
            <td>${{producto.precio}}</td>
            <td>{{producto.cantidad}}</td>
            <td>${{producto.total}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${{lista.getTotalCarrito()}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div ng-view>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La variable `lista` es local, sólo existe mientras se está ejecutando la definición de tu controlador. Por tanto, no es accesible desde el resto del código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu option esta mal escrito **producto.id** y en el click de tu boton solo bastaría cambiar la llamada a la función **lista.addAlCarrito** por **lista.addAlCarrito()**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controlador", function($scope){
    var lista = this;
    var n= 6;
    var nCarrito = 1;
    lista.productos = [
        {id: 1, nombre: "Florero vidrio", precio: 100.0},
        {id: 2, nombre: "Florero plastico", precio: 70.0},
        {id: 3, nombre: "Florero metal", precio: 80.0},
        {id: 4, nombre: "Papel kraft", precio: 50.0},
        {id: 5, nombre: "Papel celofan", precio: 40.0},
        {id: 6, nombre: "liston", precio: 30.0}
    ];
    
    lista.carrito = [];

    lista.addProducto = function(){
        var nombre = lista.nombre;
        var precio = lista.precio;

        if(nombre != "" && precio != "" && !isNaN(precio)){
            n++;
            lista.productos.push({id: n, nombre: nombre, precio: precio});

            lista.nombre = '';
            lista.precio = '';
        }
    }

    lista.addAlCarrito = function(){
        var id = lista.productoSeleccionado;
        var cantidad = lista.cantidad;
        var producto = lista.productos.find(function(obj){
            return obj.id == id;
        });
        if(producto != undefined && cantidad > 0) {
            lista.carrito.push({id: nCarrito, nombre: producto.nombre, precio: producto.precio, cantidad: cantidad, total: producto.precio * cantidad});
            nCarrito++;
        }
    }

    lista.getTotalCarrito = function(){
        var total = 0;
        lista.carrito.forEach(x => {
            total += x.total
        });

        return total;
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#menu{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
#menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul li a{
    color: royalblue;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container{
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

input[type="text"]{
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none; 
}
input[type="button"]{
    background-color: darkblue;
    border: 0;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    outline: none;
}

table{
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
thead{
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}

td{
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #eee
}

.total{
    background-color: #222 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controlador as lista">
    <h2>Añade productos a tu cuenta</h2>
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="lista.productoSeleccionado">
        <option ng-repeat="producto in lista.productos" value="{{producto.id}}">{{producto.nombre}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lista.cantidad">
    <input type="button" value="Añadir" ng-click="lista.addAlCarrito()">

    <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Producto</td>
                <td>Precio</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="producto in lista.carrito">
            <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
            <td>${{producto.precio}}</td>
            <td>{{producto.cantidad}}</td>
            <td>${{producto.total}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="total">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${{lista.getTotalCarrito()}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div ng-view>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```